# ColdFusion 9 - SQL Statement - Boolean Logic

Tags: sql, math, coldfusion, boolean-logic

I have plugged away at this. And this will be a simple little math logic problem.  But for the life of me I can not get it to function properly.

Trying to avoid double booking stuff in booking system. Current code...

```
  and schdate = #createODBCDate(schdate)#
  and ( schstart >= #createODBCTime(stime)# and 
        actend <= #createODBCTime(actend)# 
      )
```

Basically try to do a check - if say start time is 2pm on date and ends at 3pm...
I need to check if I am trying to book something that overlaps... Say trying to book at 2:15pm...
It should kick out with check saying - conflict.

So thinking this is math logic thing - not a ColdFusion thing... Just an air brain today...

Thanx for lead - I think I might have figured it - still testing...  Below seems to be working. Dev link offered insight.

```
     and schdate  = #createODBCDate(schdate)#
     and schstart < #createODBCTime(actend)# 
     and actend   > #createODBCTime(stime)#
```

Comment: and not exists (subquery to detect existing records) is your friend.

Comment: `not exists` would be appropriate for the opposite check ie If there *isn't* a conflict.

Comment: (Edit) On second thought, I ran a quick test and I think that will do it. Good job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

[Merle_the_Pearl's revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26266152/revisions) of the original query below is a little more intuitive. Basically reverse the comparisons:

```
WHERE   DateColumn = #RequestedDate#
AND     StartTimeColumn < #RequestedEndTime#
AND     EndTimeColumn > #RequestedStartTime#
```

---

I remember seeing a great thread on the topic: [Finding overlapping dates](http://forums.devshed.com/ms-sql-development-95/filtering-startdate-enddate-question-277324.html). (The ASCII illustration is a nice touch :). Assuming your bookings do not span multiple days, it should work fine for times as well.

The usual approach is to check for each type of conflict:

- Overlaps: ie Requested 9-10AM, but there's already a reservation for 9:30-11AM
- Falls within: ie Requested time is 10-11AM, but there's an existing reservation for 9-12PM
- Encompasses: ie Requested time is 12-5PM, but there's an existing reservation for 2-3PM

The link mentions a more elegant approach. Essentially it reduces all of those steps to a single filter.

```
    WHERE FE >= SD and FS <= ED
```

If it finds a match, you know there is a conflict. The translation should look something like this (untested).

```
 SELECT  Columns
 FROM    SomeTable
 WHERE   #RequestedEndTime# >= StartTimeColumn
 AND     #RequestedStartTime# <= EndTimeColumn
 AND     DateColumn = #RequestedDate#
```

**NB:** I deliberately omitted `cfqueryparam` for clarity. Obviously I would recommend using it in your actual query.